# EclipseLink and database encoding

Tags: eclipselink, content-encoding

I am a developer for a global application, which was deployed in a few countries whose languages were not a problem for us. But now, we're going to *Slovakia*, and we're having a bit of trouble with EclipseLink.

We've setup a small web application to test the text encoding on the database for their project. We're able to read data using EclipseLink, which was inserted directly on the database (SQL server), but when trying to insert using the EntityManager, EclipseLink sends a bunch of unicode chars instead, which are not 'translated' by the database, but inserted as is.

I'm kinda clueless so far, since I've tried to search on EclipseLink for documentation regarding this topic, but had no luck. Can you guys share some of your wisdom regarding this? Anyone had to support other languages using ORM frameworks, and can share their experience?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the issue is dealt with at the DBMS level. The tables that contain textual data need an appropriate type in order to handle unicode characters; in the case of SQL server, this type is 'nvarchar'.